# Use registers as parameter?

Tags: timers

I'm writing a helper class to manage timers, and I'm writing a lot of code like

```
if (timer == 1)
        ICR1 = icr;
    else if (timer == 3)
        ICR3 = icr;
    else if (timer == 4)
        ICR4 = icr;
    else if (timer == 5)
        ICR5 = icr;
```

Is there a better way to store these registers?
e.g. an array

```
timers {
{ ICR1, TCCR1A, OCR1A, OCR1B },
{ ICR2, TCCR2A, OCR2A, OCR2B }
```

etc.

to be accessed like

```
timers[1][0]
```

for ICR1.

And ultimately, how would I assign a value? e.g.

```
*timers[1][0] = 100;
```

**UPDATE:**

I solved the problem with

```
volatile uint16_t* ICRs[5];
ICRs[1] = &ICR1;
ICRs[3] = &ICR3;
ICRs[4] = &ICR4;
ICRs[5] = &ICR5;

*ICRs[1] = x;
```

Comment: afaik, since you assign to a different place each leaf, you can't use a look-up array, you need flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

registers are nothing but pointers to memory addresses. so the best way to "parameterize" them is to do so via pointers.

*assuming* that ICRi is of 8-bit types - they are NOT to be sure:

```
uint8_t *ICRs[4];  //isr pointers

//initialize the icrs
ICRs[0]=(uint8_t *)&ICR0;
ICRs[1]=(uint8_t *)&ICR1;
...

*ICRs[i]=icr; //assign value to ICRi
```

*note:* that piece of code isn't operable in reality. The way to go is to use a pointer to void. But I'm sure you can figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest creating macro definitions for the timers you want

Something along the lines of:

```
#define OCR_BY_INDEX(i) OCR##i
//...other code...
OCR_BY_INDEX(1) = value;
```

and then have the indices in an array

Comment: That's wonderful, I didn't know about the token-pasting operator, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y.aspx

Comment: Note that this does not work with variables, so `OCR_BY_INDEX(timer)` does not work. This is a good solution if you don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

You can better use a switch statement:

```
switch (timer)
{
case 1:
    ICR1 = icr;
    break;

case 3:
    ICR3 = icr;
    break;

case 4:
    ICR4 = icr;
    break;

case 5:
    ICR5 = icr;
    break;

default:
    // Handle other cases
    break;
}
```

About the variables:

You can make a 2 dimensional array:

```
typedef enum
{
   TYPE_ICR,   // Value 0
   TYPE_TCCRA, // Value 1
   TYPE_OCRA,  // Value 2
   TYPE_OCRB,  // Value 3
   TYPE_LAST,  // Value 4
} EType;

EType timers[TYPE_LAST][2];
```

You can access it by

```
timers[(int) TYPE_OCRB][0] = 3;
timers[(int) TYPE_OCRA][1] = 0;
```

Maybe the (int) cast is not needed.

You also can just iterate over the type:

```
for (int type = 0; type < (int) TYPE_LAST; type++)
{
    timers[type][0] = -1;
    timers[type][1] = -1;
}
```

Note 1: if a cast is needed probably static_cast(...) is better to use.
Note 2: I haven't tested the code above